# Python (Django) Remove Items From Choice List

Tags: python, django

I have a list of times for my web form and I need to remove some choices from the list based on `minimum` and  `maximum` minute value.

For example I want to only display times between 60 and 180 minutes

Django Form:

```
time_list = (
        ('', 'Select'),
        ('15', '15 Minutes'),
        ('30', '30 Minutes'),
        ('45', '45 Minutes'),
        ('60', '60 Minutes'),
        ('75', '1:15'),
        ('90', '1:30'),
        ('105', '1:45'),
        ('120', '2:00'),
        ('135', '2:15'),
        ('150', '2:30'),
        ('165', '2:45'),
        ('180', '3:00'),
        ('240', '4:00'),
        ('300', '5:00'),
        ('360', '6:00'),
        ('420', '7:00'),
        ('480', '8:00'),
        ('540', '9:00'),
        ('600', '10:00'),
        ('660', '11:00'),
        ('720', '12:00'),
        ('1440', '24:00'),
    ) 

min_time = 60 #defined in DB
max_time = 180 #defined in DB
```

Here I'm unsuccessfully trying to filter the list:

```
tmp = []
    for i in time_list:
        if i > min_time and i < max_time:
            tmp.append(i)
time_list =  tmp
```

Comment: Here's some hints to get you started: in your loop, `i` is a tuple, so you actually want to use `i[0]`. Next, you shouldn't be comparing strings like `'15'` with integers like `60`. Finally, you should also think about what whether you want the empty choice `''` to be included in the output.

Comment: @Alasdair , you are correct, I should have think of that and your hint would probably get me there. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change it to

```
time_list = iter(time_list)
next(time_list)
tmp = []
    for i in time_list:
        if int(i[0]) > min_time and int(i[0]) < max_time:
            tmp.append(i)
time_list =  tmp
```

Comment: It works! Thanks you for your help and your time! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In one line:

```
time_list = list(filter(lambda x: min_time < int(x[0]) < max_time, time_list[1:]))
```

If you want to include the empty choice:

```
time_list = [time_list[0]] + list(filter(lambda x: min_time < int(x[0]) < max_time, time_list[1:]))
```

Comment: WOW! Excellent and classy. Sorry I couldn't accept your answer as I have already accepted Emmanuel Mtali's answer. (btw, one too many parentheses at the end otherwise it works as a charm!)